# How to implement SlitSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm kinda newbie when it comes to coding and I would like to ask for your help. I want to have SlitSlider from Codrops on my website but it's not working. I've done like Codrops said in the article but it's not looking like a slider, it looks like all 5 slides are in one slide, just a plain text.
I hope some can explain me what I did wrong and hopefully It will works.

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.79639.js"></script>
<noscript>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styleNoJS.css" />
</noscript>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="slider" class="sl-slider-wrapper">
        <div class="sl-slider">
            <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="horizontal" data-slice1-rotation="-25" data-slice2-rotation="-25" data-slice1-scale="2" data-slice2-scale="2">
                <div class="sl-slide-inner">
                    <div class="bg-img bg-img-1"></div>
                    <h2>A bene placito.</h2>
                    <blockquote>
                        <p>You have just dined, and however scrupulously the slaughterhouse is concealed in the graceful distance of miles, there is complicity.</p><cite>Ralph Waldo Emerson</cite>
                    </blockquote>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="vertical" data-slice1-rotation="10" data-slice2-rotation="-15" data-slice1-scale="1.5" data-slice2-scale="1.5">
                <div class="sl-slide-inner">
                    <div class="bg-img bg-img-2"></div>
                    <h2>Regula aurea.</h2>
                    <blockquote>
                        <p>Until he extends the circle of his compassion to all living things, man will not himself find peace.</p><cite>Albert Schweitzer</cite>
                    </blockquote>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="horizontal" data-slice1-rotation="3" data-slice2-rotation="3" data-slice1-scale="2" data-slice2-scale="1">
                <div class="sl-slide-inner">
                    <div class="bg-img bg-img-3"></div>
                    <h2>Dum spiro, spero.</h2>
                    <blockquote>
                        <p>Thousands of people who say they 'love' animals sit down once or twice a day to enjoy the flesh of creatures who have been utterly deprived of everything that could make their lives worth living and who endured the awful suffering and the terror of the abattoirs.</p><cite>Dame Jane Morris Goodall</cite>
                    </blockquote>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="vertical" data-slice1-rotation="-5" data-slice2-rotation="25" data-slice1-scale="2" data-slice2-scale="1">
                <div class="sl-slide-inner">
                    <div class="bg-img bg-img-4"></div>
                    <h2>Donna nobis pacem.</h2>
                    <blockquote>
                        <p>The human body has no more need for cows' milk than it does for dogs' milk, horses' milk, or giraffes' milk.</p><cite>Michael Klaper M.D.</cite>
                    </blockquote>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="horizontal" data-slice1-rotation="-5" data-slice2-rotation="10" data-slice1-scale="2" data-slice2-scale="1">
                <div class="sl-slide-inner">
                    <div class="bg-img bg-img-5"></div>
                    <h2>Acta Non Verba.</h2>
                    <blockquote>
                        <p>I think if you want to eat more meat you should kill it yourself and eat it raw so that you are not blinded by the hypocrisy of having it processed for you.</p><cite>Margi Clarke</cite>
                    </blockquote>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /sl-slider -->
        <nav id="nav-dots" class="nav-dots">
            <span class="nav-dot-current"></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </nav>
    </div><!-- /slider-wrapper -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ba-cond.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.slitslider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var Page = (function() {
                var $nav = $('#nav-dots > span'),
                    slitslider = $('#slider').slitslider({
                        onBeforeChange: function(slide, pos) {
                            $nav.removeClass('nav-dot-current');
                            $nav.eq(pos).addClass('nav-dot-current');
                        }
                    }),
                    init = function() {
                        initEvents();
                    },
                    initEvents = function() {
                        $nav.each(function(i) {
                            $(this).on('click', function(event) {
                                var $dot = $(this);
                                if (!slitslider.isActive()) {
                                    $nav.removeClass('nav-dot-current');
                                    $dot.addClass('nav-dot-current');
                                }
                                slitslider.jump(i + 1);
                                return false;
                            });
                        });
                    };
                return {
                    init: init
                };
            })();
            Page.init();
            var $items = $('<div class="sl-slide sl-slide-color-2" data-orientation="horizontal" data-slice1-rotation="-5" data-slice2-rotation="10" data-slice1-scale="2" data-slice2-scale="1"><div class="sl-slide-inner bg-1"><div class="sl-deco" data-icon="t"></div><h2>some text</h2><blockquote><p>text</p><cite>Margi Clarke</cite></blockquote></div></div>');
            // call the plugin's add method
            ss.add($items);*/
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
.sl-slider-wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.sl-slider {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/* Slide wrapper and slides */

.sl-slide,
.sl-slides-wrapper,
.sl-slide-inner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
} 

.sl-slide {
    z-index: 1;
}

/* The duplicate parts/slices */

.sl-content-slice {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    opacity : 1;
}

/* Horizontal slice */

.sl-slide-horizontal .sl-content-slice {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    left: -200px;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%) scale(1);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0%) scale(1);
    -o-transform: translateY(0%) scale(1);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0%) scale(1);
    transform: translateY(0%) scale(1);
}

.sl-slide-horizontal .sl-content-slice:first-child {
    top: -200px;
    padding: 200px 200px 0px 200px;
}

.sl-slide-horizontal .sl-content-slice:nth-child(2) {
    top: 50%;
    padding: 0px 200px 200px 200px;
}

/* Vertical slice */

.sl-slide-vertical .sl-content-slice {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    top: -200px;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%) scale(1);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0%) scale(1);
    -o-transform: translateX(0%) scale(1);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0%) scale(1);
    transform: translateX(0%) scale(1);
}

.sl-slide-vertical .sl-content-slice:first-child {
    left: -200px;
    padding: 200px 0px 200px 200px;
}

.sl-slide-vertical .sl-content-slice:nth-child(2) {
    left: 50%;
    padding: 200px 200px 200px 0px;
}

/* Content wrapper */
/* Width and height is set dynamically */
.sl-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
}

.sl-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}

/* Default styles for background colors */
.sl-slide-horizontal .sl-slide-inner {
    background: #ddd;
}

.sl-slide-vertical .sl-slide-inner {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: remove */ from fourth line starting from bottom of the script

Comment: Thank you, I did, but same result.

Comment: Use this var $items  = ('<div class="sl-slide sl-slide-color-2" data-orientation="horizontal" data-slice1-rotation="-5" data-slice2-rotation="10" data-slice1-scale="2" data-slice2-scale="1"><div class="sl-slide-inner bg-1"><div class="sl-deco" data-icon="t"></div><h2>some text</h2><blockquote><p>text</p><cite>Margi Clarke</cite></blockquote></div></div>');

Comment: Thank you for your help, I did this too, same result. I think it's could be a problem from CSS, I can't post a picture, but anyway it looks wierd, the text from all slides combined in one.